# How do i add blank page in my word document?

Tags: ms-word, wordpress-theming, ms-office, document

Suppose I have word file with 10 pages(Including header footer with page numbers)
Now on page 5 I don't want any item at there(Not even header footer)
I found on internet that I can break the page and unlink the header footer. 
But problem is, from page 6 I want continue header footer.(So page should get pagr number 5)

Comment: Open your document.  Goto to the relevant section.  Double click in the header areas of the section. Look at the ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, you can break pages and unlink the header and footer. So you should insert a section break (next page) (note: NOT a page break) at the bottom of page 4 and at the bottom of page 5. Now you have 3 sections in your document:

Section 1 - page 1-4

Section 2 - page 5

Section 3 - page 6-10

Unlink the header and footer on page 5 and page 6 by unchecking "Link to previous" in the Word ribbon for the header and the footer. Now your sections 2 and 3 should have a blank header and footer (except page numbers - if your document has them, they should still be there).

In order to restart the header and footer in section 3, i.e. using the same header and footer from section 1, to the best of my knowledge you have to copy and paste the header and footer from section 1 to section 3. There's no way I know of to link the section 3 header and footer to that of section 1.

You also mentioned page numbers. These work independently of your footer settings. That is, even if you unlink footers, the page numbers will continue through the footers. And if you delete the page number on page 5 after unlinking the footer, page 6's number will still say "6". If you want it to say "5", right-click it, go to Format Page Number and choose "Start at 5".

Hope this helps!